Bose Einstein condensation: Sinc Vs Bose distribution
If $n_\epsilon$ is the momentum occupation number of a Bose gas with energy $\epsilon$, in it's condensed ground state it is a Bose Einstein distribution. However, for a homogenous gas in a 3D box, the Fourier transform (ie momentum space wavefunction) is a $\sin(\epsilon)/\epsilon$, so $n_\epsilon$ should be $|\sin(\epsilon)/\epsilon|^2$. How does that fit together?
